# Почему не меняет значение в таблице?

Tags: php, mysql

Я начинающий в PHP. Сейчас пытаюсь изменять данные в таблице. Что тут не так?

```
<?php 
session_start();
$bet = $_POST["bet"];
$result = rand (1,2);
$mysqli = new mysqli ("localhost","root","","game");
$mysqli->query("SETNAMES 'utf8'");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.login = '$_SESSION ['login']'");
echo($_SESSION['login']);
mysql>("UPDATE `game`.`users` SET `money` = '500' WHERE `users`.`name` = '$_SESSION ['login']'");
$money = $_SESSION['money'];
if($result == 1){
  $money = $money + $bet;
}
if($result == 2){
  $money = $money - $bet;
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Ошибок не выводит.

```
 mysql>("UPDATE `game`.`users` SET `money` = '500' WHERE `users`.`name` = '$_SESSION ['login']'");
```

Но вообще в данной строке должно все менять. Но почему то не меняет. В чём проблема?

Comment: Что такое `mysql>` ?

Comment: Видел такое решение в интернете где-то.

Comment: Если знаете как решить или как реализовать то что я хочу, скажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ошибки выводит, только не на экран а в файл журнала. По факту у вас идёт сравнение константы со строкой. Запрос выполняется только в строке выше.

Comment: @marmid Полагаю, что у Вас просто проблема с экранированием. Замените `'$_SESSION['login']'` На `'$_SESSION[\'login\']'`

Comment: как работает конструкция mysql> ? я лично в первый раз вижу такую конструкцию, но даже если она работает, несколько логических странностей: 1. вы сначала создаете соединение с помощью mysql**i**, а потом используется mysql. 2. если mysql обособленная конструкция, то откуда она берет соединение к БД? 3. Почему бы не использовать один стиль кодинга? если вы создаете $mysqli объект для получения данных БД, то зачем потом использовать что то другое? это делает код менее читаемым